# Java ServerSocket accept-method continous listening

Tags: java, server

I need to continuously listen to ONE client and reply with either of two messages.

I'm not sure how the accept-method works. I understand that it is opening up a connection to the client and returning that connection.

But what happens in the next loop? Does it block until the next message from the client arrives?
Also, is the code below a good approach for this problem?

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket();
while(true) {
    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

    //Retreive message from client here

    if(incomingFromClient.equals(something)) {
        ReplyThread rt = new ReplyThread(socket, reply_1);
        rt.start()
    } else if(incomingFromClient.equals(somethingElse)) {
        ReplyThread rt = new ReplyThread(socket, reply_2);
        rt.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: `while(true)` is **never** a good approach since its *effectively* a deadlock - if your runtime decides to skip the loop body *(which it can and will)* this program will never stop ... its one of the main reasons for apps crashing, forcing the user to kill processes. Use `AtomicBoolean` in the loop head and this problem is solved - and ignore all of the programming beginners which try to defend mistakes like this with all their power and free time ... beginners' mistakes will never turn into *"good code"* just because the majority of beginners want it to. My 3.14 cents.

Comment: heres how a "good" application works :
controlled startup / init --> controlled runtime --> controlled shutdown / de-init. Use it wisely and generously.

Comment: Thanks for the AtomicBoolean solution. Does the accept-method wait until the next message from the client arrives?

Comment: No, it waits for the next **client** : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept()

Comment: @rolf-ralf - That depends on whether your code for receiving message from client is blocking OR non-blocking in nature. If non-blocking, then the server will create the reply thread, and return to listen to second incoming connection request.

Comment: I .. actually dont care what *"sounds correct"*, the API documentation is pretty clear on factual reality.

Comment: Ok so I should probably put it outside the loop then, since it's only one client and a very short message.

Comment: Well ... that'll make your server-app only work **once** - looping over `accept` is pretty common for server-applications **but** you should keep it safe, stable and **as simple as possible**

Comment: @specializt A deadlock is a condtion where two or more threads or processes are doing nothing and because of at least two locks acquired in different orders. The situation you drive is an infinite loop. Not the same thing.

Comment: runtime is waiting for the java application to finish and the application is waiting for a *never-false* condition. Thats why i wrote *"effectively"*, its the exact same result

Comment: @specializt The application isn't waiting for anything. It is is a spin loop.

Comment: you're contradicting yourself with your own words. Applications which do not "wait for something" *(hence : loop over a condition and possibly yield)* immediately exit ... thats pretty basic IT knowledge; waiting == looping over conditions, some of these conditions may be provided by runtimes or even the OS-kernel, the only exceptions are hardware interrupt routines.

Comment: in fact even some of these "wait-loops" *(i just made that word up)* may be created by runtimes or operating systems instead of the application - which call application code after they're done, sometimes these calls are implemented via "callback routines". You have much to discover - enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

No. You should never do any I/O with the client in the accept loop. Otherwise a rogue client can stop the world and prevent subsequent clients from getting any service. The thread that you start for each accept socket should do all the I/O to that socket.